# Удаленный вызов openrowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, oledb

При выполнении команды на удаленной машине

```
sqlcmd -E -d HR -S 10.54.55.119 -Q "SELECT * INTO [HR].[dbo].[HR1_report] FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=\\192.168.0.6\test\test.xlsx; HDR=YES','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')"
```

получаю ошибки:
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Server RPAKF3DB1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Server RPAKF3DB1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
При выполнении той же команды локально на сервере с MSSQL все работает отлично.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: если 10.54.55.119 это Server RPAKF3DB1, то скорее всего там такой провайдер не установлен

Comment: Установлен. Локально же с этого сервера все работает

Comment: значит надо смотреть на удалённой машине, стоит ли провайдер

Comment: А разве нужен провайдер на удаленной машине? Вроде ж  вся работа с Excel на сервере с SQL происходит

Comment: sqlcmd вы запускаете на удалённой машине (не на сервере), она и участвует в работе со всеми вытекающими проблемами, ещё и доступ полный сетевой к вашему файлику экселя вам понадобится с этой машины

Comment: старая проблема https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/openrowset-not-working-from-client-machine

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: @Konst вы под удаленной машиной подразумеваете ту машину, на которой запускается sqlcmd? на ней никакой провайдер не нужен, sqlcmd просто передает команду на сервер, и больше никак в выполнении не участвует. И провайдер и файл нужны только на сервере, но при при этом у пользователя, под которым выполняется команда, должен быть доступ к  temp сервисного аккаунта sql server (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2008/07/23/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-message-unspecified-error/). Проще локально создать провайдера и данные перелить кодом :(